# Problems using git-review with our Gerrit installation

Tags: git, gerrit

After cloning a repo and making a change on a branch, I get the following when attempting to setup the remote to Gerrit:

```
$ git review -s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/git-review", line 676, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/git-review", line 643, in main
    if not set_hooks_commit_msg(remote, hook_file):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/git-review", line 122, in set_hooks_commit_msg
    parse_git_show(remote, "Push")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/git-review", line 247, in parse_git_show
    team = project_name.split("/")[-2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with git-review documented here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/git-review/+bug/980929 that has a fix committed as of 2012-04-14.

It appears to be caused by assuming a naming convention using slashes for projects.

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that you have successfully installed gerrit and you are still facing above problem, try to upgrade your git version. This solved the problem form me as well.

+Samba.